# Area calculation of MODIS snow cover

Tags: modis, time-series, snow

I am trying to Calculate NDSI Snow Cover Area in Percentage and Square Kilometers. But It code not working for me. Code giving me this error, "Error: Image.select: Pattern 'year' did not match any bands. (Error code: 3)" .

Code Link:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/f5c39d453ec47be2a4cb66adb87e051f

Code given below:

```
// Load MODIS snow cover dataset
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MOD10A1')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2001-01-01', '2022-12-31'))
                  .select('NDSI_Snow_Cover')
                  .filterBounds(roi);

// Function to calculate snow cover area in square kilometers
function calculateSnowCoverArea(image) {
  // Calculate pixel area in square kilometers
  var pixelArea = ee.Image.pixelArea().divide(1000000); // Convert square meters to square kilometers
  
  // Calculate snow-covered area in square kilometers
  var snowCoverArea = image.multiply(pixelArea).rename('NDSI_Snow_Cover');
  
  // Return the result with original image properties and date
  return image.addBands(snowCoverArea);
}

// Map over the ImageCollection to calculate snow cover area for each image
var snowCoverAreaCollection = dataset.map(calculateSnowCoverArea);

// Reduce the ImageCollection to yearly sums
var snowCoverYearly = snowCoverAreaCollection.sum();

// Create an ImageCollection with a single image representing the yearly sum
var snowCoverYearlyCollection = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([snowCoverYearly]);

// Function to calculate the year from the image timestamp and set it as an image property
function addYear(image) {
  var year = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start')).get('year');
  return image.set('year', year);
}

// Map over the ImageCollection to add the year property
var snowCoverYearlyWithYear = snowCoverYearlyCollection.map(addYear);

// Reduce the yearly data to get the snow cover area for each year
var snowCoverYearlyReduced = snowCoverYearlyWithYear.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum());

// Select only the 'year' and 'NDSI_Snow_Cover' properties for export
var snowCoverExport = snowCoverYearlyReduced.select(['year', 'NDSI_Snow_Cover']);

// Export the results to a CSV file
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: snowCoverExport,
  description: 'Yearly_Snow_Cover_Area',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});

// Center the map on the Region of Interest and add the snow cover layer to the map
Map.centerObject(roi);
```